# libxls: xls_open() crachs when a number of loaded files is exceeded

Tags: c, excel, xls

I'm using libxls library to read `.xls` files in C language. I want to load about 40 excel files.
But, when I exceed 12 files the `Function xls_open()` crashes with the following message of windows: `"segmentation default"`. When I load just 12 files, it works fine.

Can anyone tell me the maximum number of files in memory that the
   library supports?

I close each file i open by calling xls_close(). This function seems free all memory, here its code:

```
#define xls_close xls_close_WB

void xls_close_WB(xlsWorkBook* pWB)
{
OLE2*       ole;

verbose ("xls_close");

if(!pWB) return;

// OLE first
ole=pWB->olestr->ole;

ole2_fclose(pWB->olestr);

ole2_close(ole);

// WorkBook
free(pWB->charset);

// Sheets
{
    DWORD i;
    for(i=0; i<pWB->sheets.count; ++i) {
        free(pWB->sheets.sheet[i].name);
    }
    free(pWB->sheets.sheet);
}

// SST
{
    DWORD i;
    for(i=0; i<pWB->sst.count; ++i) {
        free(pWB->sst.string[i].str);
    }
    free(pWB->sst.string);
}

// xfs
{
    free(pWB->xfs.xf);
}

// fonts
{
    DWORD i;
    for(i=0; i<pWB->fonts.count; ++i) {
        free(pWB->fonts.font[i].name);
    }
    free(pWB->fonts.font);
}

// formats
{
    DWORD i;
    for(i=0; i<pWB->formats.count; ++i) {
        free(pWB->formats.format[i].value);
    }
    free(pWB->formats.format);
}

// buffers
if(pWB->summary)  free(pWB->summary);
if(pWB->docSummary) free(pWB->docSummary);

// TODO - free other dynamically allocated objects like string table??
free(pWB);
 }
```

Comment: First of all it's "segmentation *fault*", secondly are you sure the crash is in the library and not in your code? Or that it's because of something you're not doing correct? Have you tried running in a debugger to catch the crash?

Comment: Also, Windows calls them "access violations" not "segmentation faults". Where did you see that message?

Comment: @immibis I suspect that the OP is using [this `libxls`](http://libxls.sourceforge.net/) which can be built for both OSX and Linux, which have segmentation faults.

Comment: By the way, are you supposed to do some processing to all 40 files at the same time, or can you do it one by one?

Comment: Thank you @Joachim Pileborg for your answers;

- The problem is in the library i think, because when i use just 12 Excel files it works fine (I cna read files without crach).

- I tried to debugger (with MinGW debugger) the code, it crachs in xls_open.

- The message of "segmentation fault" is displayed by the debugger i think.

- The 40 files are read one by one not in the same time.

Comment: It *seems* like the problem is resource exhaustion (i.e. running out of memory), after you're done with one file do you clean up properly (i.e. close all files, free all memory, call the correct clean-up functions)?

Comment: Yes i think it is a problem of memory too. I close files at each call of xls_open() by calling xls_close(). I added its code (it is the code of the library) in the question.